# ListView not shown in android 2.2

Tags: android, android-listview, android-relativelayout

I am using listview in my application. below is the code -

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
```

Adapter -

```
public class TitleViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context mContext;
List<String> list;

public TitleViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> list) {
    mContext = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.title_view, null);
    }
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    tvTitle.setText(MidnightUtility.countriesNames[position]);

    TextView tvDescryption = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.tvDescryption);
    tvDescryption.setText(MidnightUtility.countriesNames[position]);

    ImageView imgPlus = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgPlus);
    imgPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
}
```

In activity I use this code to add listview-

```
       ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    TitleViewAdapter adapter = new TitleViewAdapter(
            SecondLevelContent.this,
            Arrays.asList(MidnightUtility.countriesNames));
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And this is my list view row-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/strip_gradient"
android:padding="10dp" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescryption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgPlus"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_add" />
```

The problem is that listview is not appearing in android2.2. The same code works on higher versions. Is there any restriction of listview on android2.2?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what "MidnightUtility" ?

Comment: Its utility class which contains array of countrynames

Comment: then why you are using "list" ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want list view to take the full screen then use match_parent otherwise use wrap_content for android:layout_height. Use match_parent for android:layout_width.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
```

The problem is that you are using android:layout_height="fill_parent" for each row. This is not correct. Each row height should be wrap_content. Use the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/strip_gradient"
android:padding="10dp" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescryption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgPlus"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_add" />
```

I think it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this method**

Use `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
```

Comment: @ByzantineFailure your assumption is wrong, please check ListActivity source code in the android repo. It is better to use `match_parent` than `wrap_content`

Comment: it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: check the ListActivity layout http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/list_content_simple.xml

Comment: I tried with both option, Its not working on android 2.2

Comment: @unflagged.destination try overriding `isEmpty()` method of the adapter and return `false`

Comment: @ByzantineFailure the authenticity of code in android repo is far more relavent than vogella.com

Comment: Tried with isEmpty() method also, still same problem exist. but its working on android higher version So is there any method which is not supported on lower versions

Comment: @ByzantineFailure you got it wrong my friend. If you use `match_parent` the listview's height will be the same as its parent view. But if you use `wrap_content` the listview will have to go and measure each of its rows and get the height. That will be what Roman Guy will be saying. Plus i find no code that document with a `listview` with height `wrap_content`